# Working with tweepy in Google App Engine - ImportError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to use the tweepy library (Twitter library in python) in my Google App Engine application. I have included the tweepy library in my application's root directory. When I try to deploy on local server, this is the error I get :

```
ERROR    2014-04-21 01:07:11,979 wsgi.py:262] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/Desktop/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/dev/Desktop/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/home/dev/Desktop/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/dev/Desktop/tweets_on_google_map/twittermap/twittermap.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tweepy
ImportError: No module named tweepy
INFO     2014-04-21 01:07:12,035 module.py:627] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Clarification-- `tweepy` is in `/home/dev/Desktop/tweets_on_google_map/twittermap/`?

Comment: @Louis Yes, its there.

Comment: try an `os.chdir('/home/dev/Desktop/tweets_on_google_map/twittermap/')` right before the `import tweepy`